# MVC @Html.TextAreaFor validation not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having an issue on a form that has textBox and textArea. This forum is in a shared view. The textBox's are validating but the textArea's are not. I've gone through a lot of issues other people have faced and haven't seemed to be able to resolve it. I created another form in my application and the validation worked on the textArea

The form is a dynamically created questions page.

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.QuestionAnswers.Count; i++)
{
        @switch (Model.QuestionAnswers[i].QuestionType)
        {
            case QuestionTypeEnum.SentenceRequired:
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.QuestionAnswers[i].Answer, 5, 20, new { @class = "input-xlarge persistLocal",
                required = "required" })
                break;


            case QuestionTypeEnum.TextBoxRequired:
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.QuestionAnswers[i].Answer, new {@class = "input-xlarge persistLocal", required = "required" })
                break;
         }
}
```

This is my model, i'm not using a attributes on the model, as when im generating the form, some of the questions are not required. and i have tried this and it still not working.

```
 public class QuestionAnswerViewModel
{

    public List<QuestionAnswer> QuestionAnswers { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
public class QuestionAnswer
{
    public string Answer { get; set; }

    public string Question { get; set; }

    public int PermitRequestTypeQuestionId { get; set; }

    public QuestionTypeEnum QuestionType { get; set; }

    public int AnswerId { get; set; }


    [DisplayName("Question")]
    public string QuestionAndAnswerText
    {
        get { return string.Format("{0} <strong>{1}</strong>", Question, Answer); }
    }
}
```

This is a screen shot of my forum

[image: Forum]

These are the scripts that are loaded into the view

[image]

In the parent view i've tried adding this to try force the validation
     $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#formName");

This is the output on the console
[image]

I thought maybe it was some white space between the two textarea tags but it doesn't seem to be and there's no errors in the javascript console window, and as i said earlier, it is working for a textbox. I've also tried changing it to a EditFor and changed the model property to use the multiline attribute and required attribute and still no joy.

Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: Have you tried to decorate the Answer property with the `[Required]` attribute?

Comment: @ataravati I did try it but didnt work, the reason I'm not doing that is because each text box might be either required or not, so I can't mark the property with the required attribute.

Comment: But, you can create a custom `RequiredIf` attribute which makes the field required depending on the value of another property in the model. Just look for RequiredIf, and you'll find one.

Comment: @ataravati il give it a try, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: By the way, your `QuestionAndAnswerText` property is a violation of MVC philosophy. You're doing what's supposed to be done in the view, in your ViewModel. Instead of doing that, you can create a partial view for QuestionAnswer model, call it `QuestionAnswer.cshtml`, and place it under `Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates`. Then, you can use `@Html.DisplayFor()` to display it.

Comment: `required = "required"` is HTML-5 validation and has nothing to do with jquery validation (there is no point adding `jquery.validate.js` and `juery.validate.unobtrusive.js` to you view or using `@Html.ValidationMesageFor()`. And your code will not give you server side validation. You need to use validation attributes applied to your properties for those to have any any meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I'm not posting back to the server from this partial view, this piece of Javascript was being used to validate the partial view

```
        var validator = $("form").validate(); // obtain validator
            var anyError = false;
            $step.find("input").each(function() {
                if (!validator.element(this)) { // validate every input element inside this step
                    anyError = true;
                }

            });

            if (anyError)
                return false; // exit if any error found
```

JQuery wasn't picking up the textArea because it wasn't present.

```
$step.find("input,textarea").each(function()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `[Required]` attribute into model for property.

Something like this:

```
[Required]
public string Answer { get; set; }
[Required]
public string Question { get; set; }
```

Comment: @InitLipton, manually create js/jq script where validates these textBox and textArea. Or you can use jQuery validate plugin from here: https://plugins.jquery.com/validate/

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace TextAreaFor with EditorFor. Since your model already has the multiline flag set, this should not impact your UI, but it should work around a potential (and past documented for some versions) bug with TextAreaFor.